# Pyautogui.click(x, y) error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

So I am learning to use python 3 and now the "pyautogui" module. When I try to use "pyautogui.click(x, y)". I get this error "[WinError 5] Access is denied". It still clicks the coordinates, but why I get this error. I have tried to run this from normal and administer CMD. I am using windows 10. If you can help me please help!

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Windows 8.1. I solved making a bat file calling the python script and running the bat file as administrator.

To run the bat file as administrator I made a right click on bat file and run as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

I found out another way. You can use two "try/except":

```
try:    
    pyautogui.click(x, y)
except:
    try:
        pyautogui.click(x, y)
    except:
        pass
```

I don't know why and how, but it works.

Comment: You could just put `pass` in your first `except` clause and get the same behavior.

Comment: That's right. In fact, I made this solution for doubleClick. Just none try/except is needed for click .

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is when you have a mouse options app installed (at least in my case).
I know it from this story: I had a python script that used click (twice). It worked well, but in the meantime, I installed a mouse settings app on my comp. After that I run my script, but got this access denied error. (However, the first click worked, only the second one gave that error). Then I uninstalled this mouse software (almost unusable anyway), and voila, the clicking was again all right.
Hope this helps you as well.